# Cannot connect to a mongos

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

I am implementing a sharded cluster in a Windows environment.

I first create the config server as follows:

```
C:\MongoDB\bin>mongod –configsvr –bind_ip 192.168.1.4 –port 3000 –dbpath C:\Sharding\configServer
```

Then I try to connect to the *mongos* instance which is listening on port 3000:

[image]

The command I use to connect to the *mongos* instance is as follows:

```
C:\MongoDB\bin>mongos –configdb 192.168.1.4:3000
```

My problem is that I cannot connect with the *mongos* instance as I get the below error. I cannot figure out what is this problem and how to solve it.  I searched on the Internet however all suggestions that I found did not solve my problem and I'm literally stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

provide a `port` option for your `mongos` instance, for example `27018`

The error messages says: `Only one usage of socket address is normally permitted for 0.0.0.0:27017`. It looks like `mongos` instance is trying to bind to a port that is already ocuppied by another process (propably `mongod`)